# How to add properties from one object into another without overwriting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, properties, addition

I'm trying to add properties from one object into another without writing over the original property.

```
//Start
obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
obj2 = {b: 4, c: 3, d: 4}

//Goal
obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
```

I've tried the following but I can't see to figure it out:

```
function mergeProp(obj1, obj2) { //obj1 is destination, obj2 is source
  for (var a in obj2) {
    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(a) && !obj1.hasOwnProperty(a)) {
      obj1[a] = obj2[a];
    }
  }
  return obj1 //returns {a: 1, b: 4, c: 3, d: 4} should have {...b: 2...}
}
```

This returns the properties overwritten. I tried variations of this, but seem to always be overwriting, or missing properties from **obj1**

I also tried this code:

```
function extend(obj1, obj2) {
  let obj = {};
  for (let a in obj2) {
    obj[a] = obj2[a];
  };
  for (let b in obj1){
    obj[b] = obj1[b];
  };
  return obj; //Returns {b: 4, c: 3, d: 4}
}
```

The object doesn't even have any of the properties from obj1.

I am aware of "...Object" but the lesson I'm practicing doesn't want me to work with that. I managed to make it work with that however.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `let obj3 = Object.assign({}, obj2, obj1);`

Comment: Your function works. `{a: 1, b: 4, c: 3, d: 4}` is the result of merging `obj1` into `obj2` so you're probably passing the arguments in the wrong order. See my answer for a snippet demonstrating this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're passing the arguments to `mergeProp` in the right order?

If I call `mergeProp(obj1, obj2)`, it returns the desired result. If I call `mergeProp(obj2, obj2)`, it returns the problem result that you are describing.

```js
//Start
var obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
var obj2 = {b: 4, c: 3, d: 4}

function mergeProp(obj1, obj2) { //obj1 is destination, obj2 is source
  for (var a in obj2) {
    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(a) && !obj1.hasOwnProperty(a)) {
      obj1[a] = obj2[a];
    }
  }
  return obj1 //returns {a: 1, b: 4, c: 3, d: 4} should have {...b: 2...}
}

console.log(mergeProp(obj1, obj2))
console.log(mergeProp(obj2, obj1))
```

Comment: I just double checked and it seems there was an error with the site. It should be working now. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 5):

**ES2015:**

```
const obj3 = Object.assign({}, obj2, obj1);
```

**ES2018:**

```
const obj3 = {...obj2, ...obj1};
```

Comment: what does passing the empty object in the first object.assign do?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the object `obj2` using `for..in` and check if `obj1` has the same key. If the key is not here in `obj1` ,add that key and value to it

```js
let obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}
let obj2 = {
  b: 4,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
}

for (var keys in obj2) {
  obj1.hasOwnProperty(keys) || (obj1[keys] = obj2[keys]);
};
console.log(obj1)
```

```html
obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
```

Comment: @MakanAzarshahy This is different from what you were trying to do in that it doesn't check whether the properties are "own" properties on `obj2`. Also this use of "clever" code to avoid just using a normal `if` statement for its intended purpose only serves to make the code harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ES6` with `arrow functions`

```js
let obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
let obj2 = {b: 4, c: 3, d: 4}


Object.keys(obj2).forEach(item => {
    if (Object.keys(obj1).indexOf(item) < 0)
        obj1[item] = obj2[item];
})

console.log(obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do it, here's another:

```js
//Start
let obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
let obj2 = {b: 4, c: 3, d: 4};

Object.keys(obj2).forEach(key => {
  if (!obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    obj1[key] = obj2[key];
  }
});

console.log(obj1);
//Goal
//obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the case in question, you would do:

```
obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
obj2 = {b: 4, c: 3, d: 4}l

console.log(Object.assign({}, obj2, obj1)); // {b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, a: 1}
```

There's no limit to the number of objects you can merge: `Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2, obj3, etc);`

- All objects get merged into the first object.
- Only the object in the first argument is mutated and returned.
- Later properties overwrite earlier properties with the same name.

Current browser [support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Object_static_methods_Object.assign) is getting better, but if you're developing for browsers that don't have support, you can use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill).

If you're using jQuery then you would do like this:

```
obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
obj2 = {b: 4, c: 3, d: 4}l

console.log(jQuery.extend(obj2, obj1)); // {b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, a: 1}
```

**Careful**: the variable `obj2` will be modified, though. jQuery doesn't return a new instance. The reason for this (and for the naming) is that .extend() was developed to extend objects, rather than to munge stuff together. If you want a new object (e.g. `obj2` you don't want to touch), you can always `jQuery.extend({}, obj2, obj1);`